# hide TabView after clicking on a NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

when I have a `TabView{}` and the first Tab has a `NavigationView`, when I click on a `Row`, I want that `TabView{}` to disappear. How do I do that?

Same Issue here: [How to hide the TabBar when navigate with NavigationLink in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304876/how-to-hide-the-tabbar-when-navigate-with-navigationlink-in-swiftui)

But unfortunately no solution.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218018/1745000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that currently. For example, `NavigationView` responds to the `.navigationBarHidden(_:)` method on its descendants, but there is not an equivalent for `TabView`.

If this is something you'd like to see, [let Apple know](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Comment: alright thanks for your answer. Then we'll have to wait

Answer (score 1):

there's no way to hide TabView so I had to add TabView inside ZStack as this:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        TabView {
            TabBar1().environmentObject(self.userData)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("First")
            }
            TabBar2()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("Second")
            }
        }

        if self.userData.showFullScreen {
            FullScreen().environmentObject(self.userData)

        }
    }
}
```

UserData:

```
  final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showFullScreen = false}
```

TabBar1:

```
struct TabBar1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        Text("TabBar 1")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(Color.green)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.userData.showFullScreen.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

FullScreen:

```
struct FullScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        Text("FullScreen")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.userData.showFullScreen.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

check full code on [Github](https://github.com/fakiho/FullScreenTabView)

there's also some other ways but it depends on the structure of the views

Comment: Good workaround! Just one thing if someone struggles to implement your above code: In SceneDelegate you have to add the environmentObject to your rootViewController like this:             window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(UserData()))

Answer (score 1):

To solve this limitation, I came out with this approach:

- Created an enum to identify the tabs

```
enum Tabs: Int {
    case tab1
    case tab2
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .tab1: return "Tab 1 Title"
        case .tab2: return "Tab 2 Title"
        }
    }

    var imageName: String {
        switch self {
        case .tab1: return "star" // Example using SF Symbol
        case .tab2: return "ellipsis.circle"
        }
    }
}
```

- Inside the view, such as `ContentView.swift`, added a property like this:

```
@State private var selectedTab = Tabs.tab1
```

- Inside the body:

```
NavigationView {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        ViewExample1()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: Tabs.tab1.imageName)
                Text(Tabs.tab1.title)
        }.tag(Tabs.tab1)
        
        ViewExample2()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: Tabs.tab2.imageName)
                Text(Tabs.tab2.title)
        }.tag(Tabs.tab2)
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(selectedTab.title)
}
```

That's all. I hope this might be helpful.

**Note:** Just be aware this workaround hides the TabView in any and all child views, if you want to hide in just a particular view, this won't give you the result that you looking for.

Hopefully, Apple implements an (official and proper) option to hide the TabView soon.

Comment: This works when you enter a child view, but when you return to the parent view at the top of the hierarchy, the TabView disappears. This is in ios 14.4 with Xcode 12.3

Answer (score -1):

Don't Use `NavigationLink`

[image: 1]

First Define this

[image: 2]

Later use this

[image: 3]

Change myFullScreenCover & isTabViewHidden Sorry

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418 will explain what the problem with your post is.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.