# UIKit Tabview to top of screen

Tags: uikit, customization, tabview

Is there a way that I can place the tabview and customize (add animations from tab to tab) it, placing it at the top of my screen rather than the bottom of it?

Comment: No. You’ll have to make it yourself.

Comment: The approach provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560140/12299030) might be helpful for your goal. If you change `ZStack` alignment on `.top` you see TabBar at top... everything else is in your hands.

Comment: @Asperi is there a way that you can make it using UIKit?