# Navigating to List View in SwiftUI immediately shifts the list upward offscreen

Tags: ios, list, scroll, navigation, swiftui

A simple `NavigationLink` to a `List` view gives me the following strange behavior. After the navigation successfully occurs, the list abruptly shifts to where the title and back button are no longer on the screen:

[image: Screen capture of strange behavior]

Here is the code (Xcode 11.5). Any idea what's going on?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ListView()) {
                Text("Go to List View ›")
            }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { person in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                        .resizable().frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                    Text("User \(person+1)")
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("List")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because you try to hide/show the `NavigationBar` in a way which is not currently supported in `SwiftUI` (it may be fixed in the next releases).

This bug in SwiftUI occurs when you try to make the NavigationBar hidden in the root view and shown in the detail view:

- [SwiftUI hiding a navigation bar only when looking at ContentView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183775/swiftui-hiding-a-navigation-bar-only-when-looking-at-contentview/62184124#62184124)
- [SwiftUI show/hide title issues with NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996266/swiftui-show-hide-title-issues-with-navigationbar)

**EDIT**

It seems like this bug was fixed in Xcode 12 beta.

Comment: Thank you, @pawello2222! I searched for awhile but didn't turn these up because I didn't realize the issue was the title-hiding carrying over. Commenting out .navigationBarHidden(true) solves the problem but leaves an annoying unusable space at the top of the ContentView. I'll hope for a fix soon!