# SwiftUI NavigationView nests TabView auto pop

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

`NavigationView` nests `TabView`, I have a `List`, and push to the next page
When the application returns to the background and returns to the active state, the push page automatically pops up.

If `TabView` nests `NavigationView`, there will be no problem, but I want `NavigationView` to nest `TabView`, is there any way to solve it

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<30) { index in
                        RowView(index: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct RowView: View {
    
    var index: Int
    @State var userViewActive: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        } label: {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4 (ie. remains on navigated view after bring to foreground)

Comment: @Asperi I can't upgrade to 13.3 for the time being, is it compatible with versions below iOS 15.4?

Comment: I can confirm my iPhone XS ( iOS 15.4.1 ) suffers the same issue

Comment: I faced the same problem. Did you manage to find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

In a tabview each tab should manage its own view state. Aka

Every tab should have it's own navigation view. If you add this, you will see that your problem is solved.