# List inside TabView inside NavigationView breaks animation for Navigation Title

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I want to have `NavigationView` starting with **Welcome** scene + `TabView` on the followup scene with `List` of items. I want `NavigationView` bar to coordinate with `List` scrolling in a "usual" way:

- if scrolling down the list, `Navigation Title` should become smaller and centered + grey background should be used
- if scrolling up to the top of the list, `Navigation Title` should become bigger and left-aligned + transparent background

So far I reviewed all recommendations given in similar posts: [1][StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736364/swiftui-problems-with-list-inside-tabviews-inside-navigationview), [2][Apple DevPortal](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/700235?login=true&page=1#780009022). All recommendations fail to address this issue.

Visual representation of current issue:

[image]

Code below has the issue with Navigation Title when TestView is opened and List is scrolled:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
        MainButton(title: "Press Me")
      }
      .navigationTitle("Welcome")
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
  }
}

struct MainButton: View {
  var title: String
  var body: some View {
    Text(title).font(.title)
  }
}

struct TestView: View {
  @State var selectedTab = 0
  var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
      List { ForEach(0..<100) { i in Text("Test Tab 0 row \(i)") } }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .tag(0)
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 1 Tab 1")
        .tabItem {
          Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
          Text("tab1")
        }
        .tag(0)
      List { ForEach(0..<20) { i in Text("Test Tab 1 row \(i)") } }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .tag(1)
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 1 Tab 2")
        .tabItem {
          Image(systemName: "face.smiling.inverse")
          Text("tab2")
        }
        .tag(1)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Tab Views")
    .background()
  }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    MainView()
  }
}
```

If I remove `TabView` on second Scene, **Navigation Title** works as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Apple does not support embedding `TabView` into `NavigationView` / `NavigationStack`. But it works other way around, e.g. if `NavigationView` is embedded in one of Tab Items.

Alternative solution & if you want to support original transition:

- **FROM** `Scene 0: NavigationStack`

  - **TO** `Scene 1: Navigation Stack + TabView`

You can always write your own `CustomTabView` and use in with Apple's `NavigationStack`. To make things a little easier your can reuse any `TabView` available on GitHub, e.g. modified `AxisTabView` from `Fabula`:

[image: Sample App]