# I am not able to overwrite NavigationItemTitle into TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, tabview, tabitem, navigationitem

I am a new in SwiftUI. I have a ContentView, in that I added NavigationView and from that NavigationView it redirect into another view which have a TabView.

```
//ContentView.swift

struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var isValidLogin : Bool = false    

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
         VStack
         {
           NavigationLink(destination: HomePage(), isActive:$isValidLogin) {
                Text("LOGIN")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                         self.isValidLogin = true
                    }
          }
        }.padding()
      }
   }
}
```

Here Code for HomePage.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomePage: View {

private enum Tab: Hashable {
    case home
    case map
}
@State private var selectedTabbar : Tab = .home

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTabbar)
    {
        HomeView()
            .tag(0)
            .tabItem{
                Text("Home")
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
            }
        
        MapView()
            .tag(1)
            .tabItem {
                Text("Map")
                Image(systemName: "map")
            }
    }.navigationBarTitle("Settings")
 }
}

struct HomePage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomePage()
    }
}
```

Here Code for MapView.swift is here

```
import SwiftUI

struct MapView: View {

var body: some View {
    Text("You are in Map Page")
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Map"), displayMode: .inline)
 }
} 
struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

My Error is : When I am setting global title to TabView property **.navigationBarTitle("Settings")** is always reflecting. But I want like that if I am setting the NavigationTitle into child view then it will display in that child view. I need like that when we tap on to Map Item that time NavigationTitle should **Map**. I am not able to find error why it is not working when we apply navigation title into child.

Any help should be Appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because in your example only the `TabView` is considered as a direct child of the `NavigationVIew` and only the navigation title set to the `TabView` is applied. This post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61970939/8697793

Comment: Thanks @pawello2222 For your help. I found one solution from this link. And it got the solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Here I changed my `HomePage`:

```
struct HomePage: View {
    @State private var selectedTabbar = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTabbar)
        {
            HomeView()
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem{
                    Text("Home")
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                }
            MapView()
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Map")
                    Image(systemName: "map")
                }  Image(systemName: "gear")
                }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(navigationBarTitle))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .accentColor(.red)
    }
}
```

And I added one extension for `HomePage`. It is setting the child view's navigation title:

```
private extension HomePage {
    var navigationBarTitle: String {
        selectedTabbar ==  0 ? "Home" : "Map"
    }
}
```

Using this extension we can set the dynamically navigation title into `TabView`.