# Run action when view is 'removed'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am developing an app which uses `UIKit`. I have integrated a `UIKit` `UIViewController` inside `SwiftUI` and everything works as expected. I am still wondering if there is a way to 'know' when a `SwiftUI` `View` is completely gone.

My understanding is that a `@StateObject` knows this information. I now have some code in the `deinit` block of the corresponding class of the `StateObject`. There is some code running which unsubscribes the user of that screen.

The problem is that it is a fragile solution. In some scenario's the `deinit` block isn't called.

**Is there any recommended way to know if the user pressed the back button in a `SwiftUI` `View` (or swiped the view away)?** I don't want to get notified with the `.onDisppear` modifier because that is also called when the user taps somewhere on the screen which adds another view to the navigation stack. I want to run some code once when the screen is completely gone.

Comment: IMO there is no generic golden-rule for this. Even onDisappear not always can be reliable. In every specific scenario/flow it might be needed different solution. So needed MRE of your issue to find appropriate solution.

Comment: Well I am showing a chat screen and when the user leaves (back button/swipe), only than should the user send an unsubscribe event to the server

Comment: This case probably can be handled with onDisappear in NavigationLink, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971653/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi this will also be called when a user taps on a user profile in the chat screen and a view will be added to the navigation stack, that is not what I want

Comment: KVO on the viewControllers property on the Navigation controller, if that part is UIKit?

Comment: There is a kind of `NavigationLink` that takes a binding and you can monitor it with `onChanged` which will happen when the user taps the back button. But if you have  UIViewController then you can also just use `viewWillDisappear` in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any recommended way to know if the user pressed the back button in a SwiftUI View (or swiped the view away)?

This implies you're using a `NavigationView` and presenting your view with a `NavigationLink`.

You can be notified when the user goes “back” from your view by using one of the `NavigationLink` initializers that takes a `Binding`. Create a custom binding and in its `set` function, check whether the old value is `true` (meaning the child view was presented) and the new value is `false` (meaning the child view is now being popped from the stack). Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var childIsPresented = false
    @State var childPopCount = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Child has been popped \(childPopCount) times")
                NavigationLink(
                    "Push Child",
                    isActive: Binding(
                        get: { childIsPresented },
                        set: {
                            if childIsPresented && !$0 {
                                childPopCount += 1
                            }
                            childIsPresented = $0
                        }
                    )
                ) {
                    ChildView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sweet child o' mine")

            NavigationLink("Push Grandchild") {
                GrandchildView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GrandchildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("")
                .font(.system(size: 100))
        }
    }
}
```

Note that these initializers, and `NavigationView`, are deprecated if your deployment target is iOS 16. In that case, you'll want to use a `NavigationStack` and give it a custom `Binding` that performs the pop-detection.